# Next route showing 404 error when using Link from next/link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js, tailwind-css

I am creating a login route. In a Navbar component I have added a Link to the login route inside a button tag, but  when I hit the route it takes me to page which shows 404 error.

--app
----pages
------component
--------Navbar.js
------login.js
----global.css
----layout.js
----pages.js

**Navbar component**

```
import Link from "next/link";


export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-row bg-nav-bar-clr justify-between px-10 py-7">
                <h1 className="text-5xl font-extrabold italic text-klove">Klove</h1>
                <div className="flex gap-10">
                    <button className=" text-xl bg-signup-btn-clr px-8 py-2 rounded-3xl">Signup</button>
                    <Link href={'login'} className="text-xl bg-login-btn-clr px-8 py-2 rounded-3xl">Login</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-evenly my-4">
                <h1 className="text-2xl">HOME</h1>
                <h1 className="text-2xl">ABOUT</h1>
                <h1 className="text-2xl">CONTACT</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ensure that login page exists just under pages directory and use href="/login" instead of href={'login'} on your link element.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using the `src` folder, and you have the `app` directory in the top level of your app, this might be that `nextjs` think that you are indeed using the `app` directory for routing and not the `pages`. So your pages directory inside the `app` folder is not considered as the router.

To fix this move the `pages` directory to the top level and remove `app`.